# why app is not responding with discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I wanted to write a code that will send an embed with all the commands so I wrote a code that works but after sending the embed it shows an error above the embed: [embed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suUW7.png). Here's the code:

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, CommandInteraction, EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js')
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        // ...
    ]
    
});

client.on('ready', async () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);

    const commands = [
        {
            name: 'pomoc',
            description: 'Wyświetla wszystkie komendy'
        }
    ];

    const commandData = commands.map(command => ({
        name: command.name,
        description: command.description
    }));

    const commandManager = await client.application?.commands.set(commandData);
    console.log(`Registered ${commandManager.size} slash commands`);
});

client.on('interactionCreate', interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

    if (interaction.commandName === 'pomoc') {
const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
  .setTitle('some title')
  .setDescription('some description')


interaction.channel.send({embeds: [embed]})


    }
});

client.login(process.env.CLIENT_TOKEN);
```

I tried this method:

```
interaction.channel.send({
  embeds: [{
    title: 'some title',
    description: 'some description',
    image: {url: 'image url'}
  }]
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're **sending a message in the interaction channel, rather than replying to the interaction itself**.

Upon calling a slash command, discord will send a request to your server and await a response. This error is due to the response timing out, as your server makes a separate request rather than responding to the initial request.

Rather than using `interaction.channel.send(details)`, you should be using [`interaction.reply(details)`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/CommandInteraction?scrollTo=reply) to respond to the interaction.